Angular Micro Frontends remoteEntry.js Not Found error
Fairly new to using JHipster. I have had some success with creating a Monolithic app with Angular and Spring Boot. I was also able to deploy to Azure and use created apps as internal utilities for our company. I'm exploring creating Microservices and using Micro Frontends. I have created two microservices and one gateway app using micro frontends. My dev environment is Windows 11. I am using Consul and have it running in a Docker container. One of the microservices uses PostgreSQL and the other one uses Microsoft SQL. I have a PostgreSQL engine and a Microsoft SQL engine running locally. I can run all three apps: 2 Microservices (CaplCommon, CaplLap) and one gateway (CaplWorkbook) from Eclipse.
I did an npm start for each of the projects and can log into all three.
When the gateway app logs in and I select the Entities menu it has the following two entries:

Failed to load caplcommon entries
Failed to load capllap entries.

I looked in the network tab for the browser developer tools and saw this: Request URL:
http://localhost:9004/services/caplcommon/remoteEntry.js
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
404 Not Found.
If I open a tab in the browser and manually enter the http://localhost:9004/services/caplcommon/remoteEntry.js, I get the following:
{
  "type": "https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
  "titl": "Not Found",
  "stats": 404,
  "detil": "No static resource services/caplcommon/remoteEntry.js.",
  "instnce": "/services/caplcommon/remoteEntry.js",
  "mesage" : " error.http.404",
 "path" : "/services/caplcommon/remoteEntry.js"
}. 

The caplcommon and capllab microservices and caplworkbook gateway springboot are not logging any errors. Had the same error for the capllap microservice
Here is the Application part of my JDL


application 
{
  config 
  {
    applicationType gateway
    packageName com.kelc.capl.gateway.workbook
    baseName CaplWorkbook
    serverPort 9092
    reactive false 
    buildTool maven 
    databaseType no
    clientFramework angular 
    serviceDiscoveryType consul
    testFrameworks [cypress] 
    enableTranslation true
    nativeLanguage en
    languages [en, es]
    microfrontends[CaplCommon,CaplLap]
  }
  
}

application 
{
  config 
  {
    applicationType microservice 
    packageName com.kelc.capl.service.common
    baseName CaplCommon
    serverPort 9093
    reactive false
    buildTool maven
    clientFramework angular 
    databaseType sql
    devDatabaseType postgresql
    prodDatabaseType postgresql
    enableHibernateCache false
    enableTranslation true
    nativeLanguage en
    languages [en, es]
    serviceDiscoveryType consul
    testFrameworks [cypress]
  }
  
  entities Organization, HierarchyEntity1, HierarchyEntity2, HierarchyEntity3, Site, ChildGroup, SchoolYear, LicensePool, Child, ChildGroupLink, CaplUser
}

application 
{
  config 
  {
    applicationType microservice 
    packageName com.kelc.capl.service.lap
    baseName CaplLap
    serverPort 9094
    reactive false
    buildTool maven
    clientFramework angular 
    databaseType sql
    devDatabaseType mssql
    prodDatabaseType mssql
    enableHibernateCache false
    enableTranslation true
    nativeLanguage en
    languages [en, es]
    serviceDiscoveryType consul
    testFrameworks [cypress]
  }
  
  entities LapChildHierarchyLink, LapSubscaleLookup, LapItemLookup, LapSoftwareSource, LapAssessment, LapBkSubscale, LapBkItem, LapBkObservation, LapBkObservationItem, LapObservationFreeFormText
}



Here is the info I in the Eclipse Console when running the CaplCommon microservice springboot:
    Application 'CaplCommon' is running! Access URLs:
    Local:      http://localhost:9093/
    External:   http://10.172.40.76:9093/
    Profile(s):     [dev, api-docs]

Here is the info I get in the Eclipse Console when running the CaplLap microservice springboot
    Application 'CaplLap' is running! Access URLs:
    Local:      http://localhost:9094/
    External:   http://10.172.40.76:9094/
    Profile(s):     [dev, api-docs]

Here is the info I get in the Eclipse console when running the CaplWorkbook gateway springboot
    Application 'CaplWorkbook' is running! Access URLs:
    Local:      http://localhost:9092/
    External:   http://10.172.40.76:9092/
    Profile(s):     [dev, api-docs]

Here is what is shown when running "npm start" from the CaplCommon workspace folder:
Compiled successfully.
[Browsersync] Proxying: http://localhost:4201
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
       Local: http://localhost:9000
    External: http://10.172.40.76:9000
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://10.172.40.76:3001

My browser opens at this point and goes to http://localhost:9000, which opens up the Welcome, Java Hipster (Capl Common) page from which I can login and access the Entities menu and see all of the CaplCommon entities
Here is what is shown when running "npm start" from the CaplCommon workspace folder:
Compiled successfully.
[Browsersync] Proxying: http://localhost:4202
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
       Local: http://localhost:9002
    External: http://10.172.40.76:9002
          UI: http://localhost:3002
 UI External: http://10.172.40.76:3002

My browser opens at this point and goes to http://localhost:9002, which opens up the Welcome, Java Hipster (Capl Lap) page from which I can login and access the Entities menu and see all of the CaplLap entities
Here is what is shown when running "npm start" from the CaplWorkbook workspace folder:
Compiled successfully.
[Browsersync] Proxying: http://localhost:4200
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
       Local: http://localhost:9004
    External: http://10.172.40.76:9004
          UI: http://localhost:3003
 UI External: http://10.172.40.76:3003

My browser opens at this point and goes to http://localhost:9004, which opens up the Welcome, Java Hipster (Capl Workbook) page from which I can login and when I click on the Entities menu I see:
Failed to load caplcommon entities
failed to load capllap entities
There is nothing running on port 8080

Are you starting your apps with Maven/Gradle or using npm start? The reason I ask is because port 9000+ often refers to the latter. If you start all your services with Maven/Gradle, does it work or do you still get 404s?

I am starting the springboot/backend part with Maven and it comes up and with the debug logging turned on I see that it successfully starts. I then to go the root of the project and use the npm start command. For each of the three projects it brings up a webpage, using a different port. The two micro services are able to access the Entities without error, it's just that the gateway gets the 404

After I read my last comment I realized that was not totally correct. I start the springboot apps in Eclipse in debug mode and then open up a terminal to run the npm start command. So I have three springboot apps running in debug in Eclipse (2 microservices and 1 Gateway) and then 3 terminal sessions where I have ran npm start for each one.

If you're running in debug mode, is the gateway still running on port 8080?

I added additional details in the description about starting with how my applications are declared in the JDL and then followed by the information I see in the Eclipse console and the terminal sessions when using the npm start command

Please enter a new issue in the JHipster project on GitHub with steps to reproduce. You can link back to this question to make things easier.
